# Solution for a non-linear first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have only studied methods for solving linear first order differential equations and one method my book discussed was to come up with a integral of L.H.S. But the question I am solving (maybe) doesn't have an integral.
The question is $$\ (1+y^2)\sin(2x)+(1+\cos^2(x))y'=0$$

So the first step is to to come with a function whose derivative is equal to left hand side. How should I come up with that function?

Comment: This is a separable first order equation, are you sure you have written it down here correctly?

Comment: Is it correct now?

Comment: $$\frac{y'}{1+y^2}=-\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin^2x}=-2\cot x\implies\cdots$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\ (1+y^2)\sin(2x)+(1+\cos^2(x))\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
$$\ (1+y^2)\sin(2x)=-(1+\cos^2(x))\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\ \frac{(1+y^2)\sin(2x)}{(1+\cos^2(x))}=-\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\ \frac{\sin(2x)}{(1+\cos^2(x))}dx=-\frac{dy}{(1+y^2)}$$
$$\ ∫\frac{\sin(2x)}{(1+\cos^2(x))}dx=-∫\frac{dy}{(1+y^2)}$$
$$\ -\tan^{-1}y=-\ln((1+\cos^2(x))$$
$$\ \tan^{-1}y=\ln((1+\cos^2(x))$$
$$\ y=\tan(\ln((1+\cos^2(x)))$$

Answer (score 1):

From
$$-(1+y^2)\sin(2x) = \sin^2(x)y'$$
we get that
$$\dfrac{y'}{1+y^2}=- \dfrac{\sin(2x)}{\sin^2(x)}=-2\dfrac{\cos(x)\sin(x)}{\sin^2(x)}= -2\dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$
Hence $y=...$

Comment: I think we can simply equate $$\ -\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin^2(x)} = -\frac{d}{dx}ln(\sin^2x)$$. I understand your method (I have approached the answer in that way). But the answer in my textbook is in form of $\ ln(\sin^2(x)$ so I wanted to get the answer in that way.

Comment: @FaiqRaees An antiderivative of $-2\dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$ is $-2\ln(\sin(x))=-\ln(\sin^2(x))$, so it results in the same!

Comment: My book is giving the answer $$\ y=\tan(\ln(1+\cos^2(x))) $$. Can you check if it's correct?

Comment: Oh I am deeply sorry. Can you check the question again? I made a small error when writing the question.

Comment: Btw thanks for the help. I managed to solve the question myself